# Generate Service Schedule between two Dates in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an Asp.net project using C#. I am facing a problem in this project. This task based on service scheduled according to condition.

**Problem:**

Two textboxes for dates, one dropdownlist for type

First I have selected two dates according to type generate scheduled.

For example:

I have selected dates `14/03/2014` to `14/6/2014` and type `Monthly`

Monthly means increase value by 1 month

So the output should look like this

```
14/04/2014
14/05/2014
14/06/2014
```

There are three dates that are scheduled between two date range

**Question:**

How to achieve this task ?

**Sorry for poor English.....**

Answer (score 0):

Looping and adding one month at a time should work

```
public IEnumerable<DateTime> GenerateDates(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
  var dates = new List<DateTime>();

  var date = new DateTime(start.Year, start.Month, start.Day);
  while (date.Month <= end.Month && date.Year <= end.Year)
  {
    date = date.AddMonths(1);
    dates.Add(date);
  }

  return dates;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var listDates = GetDates(new DateTime(2014, 3, 14), new DateTime(2014, 6, 14), "Day").ToList();



   public IEnumerable<DateTime> GetDates(DateTime from, DateTime to,string type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case "Month":
                {
                   for (var dt = from.AddMonths(1); dt <= to; dt=dt.AddMonths(1))
                   {
                      yield return dt;
                   }
                    break;
                }
            case "Day":
                {
                    for (var dt = from.AddDays(1); dt <= to; dt = dt.AddDays(1))
                    {
                        yield return dt;
                    }
                    break;
                }
        }

    }
```

If you need to include the `'14/03/2014'` in the result, just remove `from.AddMonths(1)` from the for loop

Answer (score 0):

From your question I assume that there are several modes, not just `MONTHLY`. Therefore I'd propose to add a registry that contains the possible modes and the function that is used to determine the next date. This registry is easily extensible if you want to offer some more modes. The sample uses a string key, but you can also use a enum.

As it is implemented now, the start date is included in the list of dates whereas the end date isn't. You can change this by tweaking the `while` loop.

```
class ScheduleDateProvider
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, Func<DateTime, DateTime>> modesDict;

    static ScheduleDateProvider()
    {
        // Register modes 
        modesDict = new Dictionary<string, Func<DateTime, DateTime>>();
        modesDict.Add("Quaterly", (dt) => dt.AddMonths(3) );
        modesDict.Add("Monthly", (dt) => dt.AddMonths(1) );
        modesDict.Add("Weekly", (dt) => dt.AddDays(7) );
        modesDict.Add("Daily", (dt) => dt.AddDays(1) );
    }

    public IEnumerable<DateTime> GetDatesInRange(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, string mode)
    {
        // Assemble dates in a list
        var getNextDateFct = modesDict[mode];
        var lst = new List<DateTime>();
        while(startDate < endDate)
        {
            lst.Add(startDate);
            startDate = getNextDateFct(startDate);
        }
        return lst.AsReadOnly();
    }
}
```

The following code shows how to use the code:

```
void Main()
{
    DateTime startDate = DateTime.Today;
    DateTime endDate = DateTime.Today.AddYears(1);
    string selectedMode = "Monthly";

    var scheduleDateProv = new ScheduleDateProvider();
    var dates = scheduleDateProv.GetDatesInRange(startDate, endDate, selectedMode);

    foreach(var dt in dates)
        Console.WriteLine(dt.ToShortDateString());
}
```